# How to access a Magento's Extension's attributes via the /v1/Customer API?

Tags: api, magento2

We use an extension called "Login As Customer", and I'm trying to update its

```
Allow Login as Customer
```

field via API on all customer records.

When creating token access I see "Login As Customer" as an available API to which to grant access (pictured), but when I curl to our /rest/V1/customers/ endpoint, I don't see any extension attributes/data related to this extension.  I'm pretty new to extensions and how they work through API, but I've been able to curl and update data before to our catalog, orders and invoices. Thanks for any help

[image: Login As Customer Token Access]

Answer (score 1):

- Please check if your extension has an acl.xml file or not please create /etc/acl.xml and add below code for your extension. The extension needs acl.xml in etc folder for the show in roles.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Companyname_Vendor::config" title="Extension title" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```